# How to display data in NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

language: Objective-C,
I'm new at iOS development so please guide me in a easiest way if you can, i'm saving data into dictionary then `NSUserDefaults` after that i want to get the data from they `NSUserDefaults`, I'm working when user clicked in a texfield then text should be stored into dictionary but when i check into Xcode after setting a break points dictionary shows `nil`. I'm sending screenshots and code please help me.
Thanks

[initialization of dictionary in viewDidLoad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpFuo.png)

[save to NSUserDefaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLFFj.png)

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    //we'll use the following method if the TF is out of the table means not in a cell.

    if([textField isEqual:self.getNameLabel]){
        [nameDateDict setObject:[textField text] forKey:K_NAME];
        [self saveToNSUserDefaults];
    }
}
```

Xcode-output

```
nameDateDict    NSMutableDictionary *   nil 0x0000000000000000
```

Sorry the name of texfield is `getNameLabel`, I'll edit it later so please don't confuse after reading the name.
Even that i've checked this code is working

```
[timeDict setObject:@"Hello" forKey:@"Greetings"];
    [timeDict setObject:@"Bye"   forKey:@"B_Key"];
    [timeDict setObject:@"what?" forKey:@"W_Key"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:timeDict forKey:@"Greetings"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:timeDict forKey:@"B_Key"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:timeDict forKey:@"W_Key"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    timeDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Greetings"];
    timeDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"B_Key"];
    timeDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"W_Key"];
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. You're not filling the dicitionary but replacing it over and over. I strongly suggest to start with a beginner's guide on programming.

Comment: then can you suggest me how to fill the dictionary with data?

Comment: Your whole code shows a complete lack of understanding for dictionaries and how they work. Read up about them, your code just doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Ok thanks i'm beginner well thanks for guiding me

Comment: Got it, you was right i was replacing the keys thanks but how can i give you rating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)theTextField {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
  }
  -(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     [self saveToNSUserDefaults:@{@"keyName":textField.text}];
  }
  -(void)saveToNSUserDefaults:(NSDictionary *)dict{
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:@"myDictionary"];
  }
  -(void *)retrieveFromNSUserDefaults{
      NSDictionary *tempDict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myDictionary"]];
      NSlog(@"TextField Value: %@",[tempDict objectForKey:@"keyName"]);
  }
```

The way you are storing the dictionary was not correct. Please go through the https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html for more about how to use them.
Everyone came from a beginner's stage but try not to skip the basics.

Comment: Yes i've noticed i was making mistake i've solved it out well thanks a lot :) basically i forgot to add the name (string value) i was adding dictionary again and again.

Comment: Yeah, it happens sometime. Don't worry keep going.

Comment: thanks even that i had posted the other code there i was working and that gave me correct answer that's why i worried

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are going on here. First, you have a scope problem, in that your create a local dictionary object in viewDidLoad, which you can't access later. It looks as though you'll want to have an NSMutableDictionary property available for the class, which should be designated either in the header file or interface extension in the implementation file (depending on your use of this dictionary in your project):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *nameDateDictionary;
```

Second, you aren't correctly initializing or accessing your dictionary and it's objects. So, (using some literal syntax shortcuts) your viewDidLoad and saveToNSUserDefaults methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *name = [defaults objectForKey:K_NAME];
    NSDate *startDate = [defaults objectForKey:K_START_DATE];
    NSDate *endDate = [defaults objectForKey:K_END_DATE];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:@{K_NAME: name,
                                                                                  K_START_DATE: startDate,
                                                                                  K_END_DATE: endDate}];
    self.nameDateDictionary = dict;        
}

- (void)saveToNSUserDefaults
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = self.nameDateDictionary;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject:dict[K_NAME] forKey:K_NAME];
    [defaults setObject:dict[K_START_DATE] forKey:K_START_DATE];
    [defaults setObject:dict[K_END_DATE] forKey:K_END_DATE];

    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As on your screenshots you are storing dictionary values in a wrong way, you store each time the whole dictionary to each `NSUserDefaults` key. It schoul be like that:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[dict objectForKey:@"key"] forKey:@"key"];
```

To get back a value from `NSUserDefaults` to dictionary:

```
[dict setObject:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key"] forKey:@"key"];
```

Comment: Yes i've noticed i was making mistake i've solved it out well thanks a lot :)